# Any character in the last row and column of the table in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to display using postgresql any character (e.g. @) in the last column and last row of the sql result table? And only there!

| column1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | last column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| row2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |
| row3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |  |
| row4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |  |
| last row | 5 | 5 | 5 | @ |

Comment: `case when row_number() over (order by column1 desc) = 1 then '@' else null end`

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last row" unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks a lot! It works perfect! I just had to sort the results by the same column.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Yeah, until you sort. Thaks for your answer.